# If, else, and elif in Python 3 - Why is my ELSE command always executing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

Why is my else command being called despite one of the 3 large if statements being true. I thought that ELSE only gets executed if none of the prior if/elif statements are true, what am I missing here?

```
import random

while True:
    computer = random.choice(["rock", "paper", "scissors"])
    user_input = "rock"

    user_input = input("Rock, Paper, or Scissors? \n Write your weapon of choice here: ")
    user_input = user_input.lower()

    if user_input == "rock":
        if computer == "rock":
            print("You both chose rock!")
        if computer == "paper":
            print("You put rock to paper, you lost!")
        if computer == "scissors":
            print("You rocked the computer's scissors, you won!")

    if user_input == "paper":
        if computer == "rock":
            print("You put paper over the computer's rock, you won!")
        if computer == "paper":
            print("You both chose paper, it's a tie!")
        if computer == "scissors":
            print("You chose paper into scissors... You lost!")

    elif user_input == "scissors":
        if computer == "rock":
            print("The computer rocked your scissors, you lost!")
        if computer == "paper":
            print("You cut up the computer's paper, you won!")
        if computer == "scissors":
            print("You both chose scissors, it's a tie!")
    else:
        print("Sorry I don't understand, please choose either 'rock' 'paper' or 'scissors'")
```

here is the output:

```
C:\Users\Darkm\PycharmProjects\TestProjects\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/Darkm/PycharmProjects/TestProjects/RockPaperScissorsGame.py
Rock, Paper, or Scissors? 
 Write your weapon of choice here: rock
You put rock to paper, you lost!
Sorry I don't understand, please choose either 'rock' 'paper' or 'scissors'
Rock, Paper, or Scissors? 
 Write your weapon of choice here:
```

Comment: use elsif in "paper" as well

Comment: You need to link the first and the second block with `elif`, not just `if`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if user_input == "rock"` is not related to the following `if - elif - else`, so even if it's true the `else` will be executed. Change

```
if user_input == "paper"
```

to

```
elif user_input == "paper"
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are having two 'if' statements, it's considered as two different blocks.

Hence, 'else' is part of your second 'if' block.

You can change your second 'if' to 'elif' to make it work.

```
if user_input == "paper":
```

to something like:

```
elif user_input == "paper":
```

Then it will be a single block, and will give your desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the second if statement with an elif and it should work fine:
[REPL](https://repl.it/repls/KlutzyFarSpreadsheets)